# What are decision feedback equalizer advantages over linear eq?

Tags: equalizer

I am studying linear and DFE equalization theory. So, the books and the Internet are saying, that linear equalizer uses to inverse z-domain channel function. That means that fir in z-domain with $H(z)$ turns channel tansfer function to $C(z)=1/H(z)$ in the case for no AWGN.  I understand it this way: For example, for channel taps $h_1=0.4;h_2=-0.02;$ we have z-domain function $H(z)=0.4-0.02z^{-1}$. And the inverse (with given the delay) of this can be presented as: $C(z)=\frac1{z^{-2}H(z)}=\frac1{0.4z^{-2}-0.02z^{-3}}=2.5z^{-2}+\frac18z^{-3}+\frac1{160}z^{-4}+R(z)$ where $R(z)$ is the approximation error. Here we can see that first fir coefficient $2.5z^{-2}$ works like a noise gain, and so, that is the main disadvantage of the linear eq. 
   It is also said that decision feedback equalizer does not use to gain power noise in spectral nulls. Can anyone tell me how it does this?  What are the advantages of DFE over linear eq? Which types of the ISI feedfworward and feedback filters use to compensate?
Sorry for my English.
Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Sorry for my English. It is not my native language.